# Unittests of TCP machine-state for my own http server

Tags: java, apache, unit-testing, tcp, tcpserver

I work with new implementation of http server. I am going to create unit tests, which will help me check whether state-machine of my TCP connection states works properly.

Of course I need to check simple things like: is my server switch to `closed` state after receiving `RST` or is it switch to `established` after sequence `SYN, SYN+ACK, ACK`.

Because the number of possible paths in this state-machine is quite big, I am wondering on which tests should I focus.

Is for instance Apache has any public unittests from which I can take a pattern?

The second thing is... that I should start creating this tests from application point of view, so I should focus on creating tests which I can simulate using simple java sockets, using commands like `connect`, `send`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**What to test**

The general goals of every unit-testing strategy are:

1. **full code coverage**: That means that each line of code of your application is at least executed once during the full test suit.
2. **full coverage of the specification**: Usually, software development starts with a functional specification which exactly states what the software does and how it reacts in each possible scenario. Each requirement mentioned in the specification needs at least one test. When you don't have a specification, a guideline for a minimum of tests could be [the specification of the HTTP protocol itself](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Whenever you test a server application, you have to keep in mind that you can't assume that your clients will be perfect implementations of the HTTP protocol. In the real world your server will be confronted with clients which implement it wrongly or which have unreliable connections which terminated abruptly during any state of your application. And that doesn't even account for malicious clients which intentionally try to find and exploit vulnerabilities in your server. These are also situations you need test-cases for.

Servers are often multi-threaded. That means that the usual problems which come with multi-threading (like race conditions, deadlocks, synchronization issues, busy spins etc.) should be tested. Unfortunately these problems are hard to predict and even harder to write meaningful unit-tests for. Not only because these problems usually manifest through interactions of different components, which is the scope of integration- and system tests, not unit tests.

**How to test**

Unit-tests should generally not depend on an external resource, because when they do you are testing that resource, not your own application. When the functionality of your application relies heavily on an external system, like it is the case of a http server, that other system should be simulated.

This is done by implementing the external resource with [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). Mock objects are objects which take the place of an object which depends on an external resource (by either extending it or by implementing the same interface), but only simulates its behavior. In the context of a webserver you would create a class which extends [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), but overrides all the methods of Socket with something which simulates an external client without actually accessing the network.

You then use this to test your classes instead of a normal socket during your unit tests.

This allows you to easily implement special mock sockets to test special test conditions, like a client which responds slowly, very fast, or just wrong.

You might wonder "But how should I do this when I create a `new Socket()` inside of the class I want to test"? The answer is that in order to make an application unit-testable you shouldn't do this. The keyword is [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection). Dependency Injection in a nutshell means that a class should never use the `new` keyword, unless it's a Factory or Builder for that kind of class. Any objects which are used by a class shouldn't be created by it. They should be supplied to it with the constructor or with setter methods.

*Example:*

So when you have a `ConnectionListener` class, which uses a `ServerSocket` to wait for clients to connect and then does something with them, you shouldn't create that ServerSocket in its constructor. Instead of that you should pass a ServerSocket to the constructor of ConnectionListener. In the production code, this would be [a normal server socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). But in you unit test you have the ability to pass a mock object which extends ServerSocket. This mock object would simulate one or more clients, and then report to the unit test framework if the ConnectionListener behaved like expected.

Answer (score 3):

> Of course I need to check simple things like: is my server switch to closed state after reciving RST or is it switch to established after sequence SYN, SYN+ACK, ACK.

Of course *not.* You have no business to be testing any of this. If the vendor's TCP/IP stack is broken it will become apparent quickly enough, all over the world. Testing it is the vendors responsibility. What you should be testing is your own code, in your own new HTTP server.

Answer (score 2):

> Is for instance Apache has any public unittests from which I can take a pattern?

You can have a look at [Apache Tomcat tests](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/test/org/apache/).

Answer (score 2):

I would start by creating a state-machine diagram, then create the tests based on the number of individual state transitions (which is a finite number, and possibly quite small).